# Adding sub folders and files to menu strip

Tags: vb.net, menuitem

Basically, I'm trying to populate a menu strip with a list of directories from a static location and then nested any sub directories underneath its parent and then display the files in the folder

I've got the basic

```
Dim loc As String = "C:\test\"

For Each dirs As String In Directory.GetDirectories(loc)
    Dim dirinfo As New DirectoryInfo(dirs)
    p1.DropDownItems.Add(dirinfo.Name)
Next
```

Which gives me the first line of directories but just not to sure where to go from here. Ultimately I would then like to be able to open the files form here.

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, this would be a *horrible* user interface if there were more than 1 level of nesting in the file system. If you want this to be usable, strongly consider an alternative mechanism, like a TreeView control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, though it seems to only go four levels deep

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' assuming you have a single top level menu item named p1
    Dim loc As String = "C:\test\"
    AddSubDirsToMenuRecursive(p1, loc)
End Sub

Private Sub AddSubDirsToMenuRecursive(m As ToolStripMenuItem, d As String)
    Dim dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(d)
    For Each dir As String In dirs
        Dim dirinfo As New DirectoryInfo(dir)
        Dim mi As New ToolStripMenuItem(dirinfo.Name)
        m.DropDownItems.Add(mi)
        m.DropDownItems.AddRange(
            dirinfo.GetFiles.Select(Of ToolStripMenuItem) _
            (
                Function(fi As FileInfo) New ToolStripMenuItem(fi.Name)
            ).ToArray())
        AddSubDirsToMenuRecursive(mi, dirinfo.FullName)
    Next
End Sub
```

If you are interested in opening the file when clicking it, replace the `m.DropDownItems.AddRange` block with this

```
m.DropDownItems.AddRange(
    dirinfo.GetFiles.Select(Of ToolStripMenuItem) _
    (Function(fi As FileInfo)
         Dim mi1 = New ToolStripMenuItem(fi.Name)
         AddHandler mi1.Click,
             Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                 Process.Start(fi.FullName)
             End Sub
         Return mi1
     End Function
    ).ToArray())
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Needs a bit of work to get where I want but its really helped alot